# How to get the week start date and end date based on the current date in Javascript side

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to get the week start date and end date based on the current date in Lightning component Javascript side.

Current date:

```
date ################Fri Aug 10 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I need to get the current week beginning and ending based on current date.

for example: acccording to current date

start of week -6/8/2018
End of week - 13/8/2018

---

tried:

```
      var startDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    alert('date '+new Date(startDate));

 var curr = startDate; // get current date
  var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the 
      month - the day of the week
   var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6     
     var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
       var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
```

facing error:

```
                [curr.getDate is not a function]
```

Comment: Quick note, this question is not related to Salesforce and is better suited for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check post https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210450

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
alert(firstday);
alert(lastday);
```

Run this code here https://www.w3schools.com/jS/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst

Comment: You should never use `var` anymore in 2018.

Comment: I didnt get Adrian Larson? why ?